# Design patterns ? how can i understand them

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

Hey guys , i'm a software Eng. student at my third year 
now i'm taking design patterns in a " software Design " course 
the problem is that those stuff are really hard to get 
do you know any simplified guide or videos to understand those concepts ?! 
my major is exam is next week and i need to prepare early , i hope you can give the simplest reference to understand them

Comment: LOL:  _...major exam is next week and I need to prepare_ ...`EARLY`? !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would check out [Heads First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) by Kathy Sierra.  She was the person who created the Heads First Series.  It's much easier to understand compared to the [Gang Of Four Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) (although this is a good book), and it's set as a tutorial, and not just a book which talks about them.

Comment: Defintely the best book to get the understanding of design pattern quick and easy.

Comment: +1. Definitely more fun than the GoF book ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book does a good job at making things easy to understand if you're having issues.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to search at stackoverflow..

Some links on a quick search

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read

[Learning/Implementing Design Patterns (For Newbies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244706/learning-implementing-design-patterns-for-newbies)

[How to study design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315000/how-to-study-design-patterns)

As you can see on the links [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/) is at the top on all of them.. so I would go for that one!

Answer (score 0):

The ***concept*** of  design pattern is actually very easy and quick to understand.
What you may have difficulties with is the understanding of ***individual patterns*** as some of these can be relatively abstract or complicated and this difficulty may be compounded by attempts to apply a given pattern to a situation where it doesn't really fit.  (That's why a key component for a properly defined pattern, as the [**GoF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) taught us, is its Applicability section).

A suggestion is to first learn a few, relatively simple / intuitive patterns (say, maybe, [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) and [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)) and to seek cases where these are applicable or not and to understand how/why they work and how they'd contribute to a better design.

Once such familiarity with simple patterns is achieved, with practice, along with the at-large-understanding of what patterns are and how they should be learned, you can then expand your panoply of patterns (and be sure to use them when appropriate: if you don't use them you loose them!).

The -pardon my pun- pattern discussed above about learning patterns, is **better applied to "life-long" interest in software design than to the context of a "major exam *next week*"** as is the case of the OP, never the less the advice may stick as well (depending on the format of the exam):

- step back, relax!, and understand what patterns are, *as a concept*
- learn one or two simple patterns, "in depth", do the exercices etc.
- skim through the list of patterns expected to be included in the exam, focusing on applicability and on the diagram which shows the interactions of the object/actors in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here simple article but good for beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28309/Design-pattern-FAQ-Part-1-Training